# Ошибка при использовании django formset

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как клонировать форму, заданное количество раз. В идеале хочу добиться, чтобы пользователь выбирал сколько бумаг нужно - редирект на страницу с соответствующим количеством форм. Нагуглил, что можно использовать `formset` для этого. В итоге никак не могу побороть ошибку `ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with`

используется `django-datetime-widget` и `django-crispy-forms`

`forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import *
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import *
from datetimewidget.widgets import DateWidget

class InputDates(forms.Form): 
# форма для ввода даты начала, конца периода и названия бумаги
    Date_start = forms.DateField(widget=DateWidget(
        # attrs={'id':"datetimeid1"},
        usel10n = True,
        bootstrap_version=3
    ),
        label='Начало периода',
        required=True,
    )

    Date_end = forms.DateField(widget=DateWidget(
            # attrs={'id':"datetimeid2"},
            usel10n = True,
            bootstrap_version=3
        ),
        label='Конец периода',
        required=True,
    )

    Stock = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=(   ('GG', 'Google'),
                    ('APPL', 'Apple'),
                    ('SR', 'Сбербанк'),
                    ('GZ', 'Газпром'),),
        required=True,
        label='Выбор бумаги'
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InputDates, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('Stock'),
            Field('Date_start'),
            Field('Date_end'),
        )

class BTN(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BTN, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Провести расчеты', css_class='btn btn-default')
            ),
        )
```

`views.py` :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

def stocks(request):
    btn = BTN(request.POST or None)
    StocksFormset = formset_factory(InputDates, extra=2)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = StocksFormset(request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'home.html')

    else:
        formset = StocksFormset()

    return render(request, 'stocks.html', {'formset' : formset, 'BTN' : btn})
```

`stocks.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post" class="text-left">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
          {% crispy form form.helper %} 
    {% endfor %}
</form>
    {% crispy BTN BTN.helper %}

{% endblock %}
```

Пытался разобраться с документацией `Django` по `formset` но там написано, что нужно лишь добавить `{{ formset.management_form }}` и все заработает. Но на практике этого не произошло

Answer (score 0):

Думаю дело в crispy. В [документации](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_formsets.html) написан пример `{% crispy formset helper %}`. У вас же, криспи применяется отдельно к каждой форме. Наверно и так можно сделать, но нужно выключить генерацию тега `form` так `FormHelper.form_tag=False`. Впрочем, вышеупомянутую ошибку не наблюдаю. Вижу только кривой html.

Рабочий вариант (python 2.7, django 1.10):

`views.py`

```
# coding=utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import *
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import *
from datetimewidget.widgets import DateWidget


class InputDates(forms.Form):
    Date_start = forms.DateField(widget=DateWidget(
        usel10n=True,
        bootstrap_version=3
    ),
        label='Начало периода',
        required=True,
    )

    Date_end = forms.DateField(widget=DateWidget(
        usel10n=True,
        bootstrap_version=3
    ),
        label=u'Конец периода',
        required=True,
    )

    Stock = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=(('GG', u'Google'),
                 ('APPL', u'Apple'),
                 ('SR', u'Сбербанк'),
                 ('GZ', u'Газпром'),),
        required=True,
        label=u'Выбор бумаги'
    )


class InputDatesSetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InputDatesSetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.layout = Layout(
            Field('Stock'),
            Field('Date_start'),
            Field('Date_end'),
        )
        self.render_required_fields = True
        self.add_input(Submit("submit", u'Провести расчеты', css_class='btn btn-default'))


def stocks(request):
    StocksFormset = formset_factory(InputDates, extra=2)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = StocksFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'home.html')
    else:
        formset = StocksFormset()
    return render(request, 'stocks.html', {'formset': formset, 'helper': InputDatesSetHelper()})
```

`stocks.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

{% crispy formset helper %}

{% endblock %}
```